# Note-Info Form not auto-populating on click on Edit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

After clicking on edit button the note information is not auto populating with the information. I have checked with everything but it is working the same in every case

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetching = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/notes/${match.params.id}`);

    setTitle(data.title);
    setContent(data.content);
    setCategory(data.category);
    setDate(data.updatedAt);
  };

  fetching();
}, [match.params.id, date]);
```

Whole code is available on this link - https://github.com/JavaKaran/Notes-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the brackets in the data object.

`const data = await axios.get(`/api/notes/${match.params.id}`);` // Remove { } from response object